# How does a closure work when there's only one parameter but two variables in it?

Tags: javascript, closures

Here's the function that I'm talking about:

```
function multiplier(factor) {
    return number => number * factor;
}

let twice = multiplier(2);
console.log(twice(5));

// output → 10
```

In this function shouldn't `number` be undefined since we're only giving one parameter. And that parameter gets multiplied and stored in number.. but anything that multiplies with `undefined` is `NaN`, right? Is the `number = 1` here somehow?

Comment: let twice = multiplier(2); // 2 is factor; console.log(twice(5)); // 5 is number

Comment: Right.. but how does it get assigned like that? Can you answer with an explanation please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function multiplier(factor) {
    return number => number * factor;
}
let twice = multiplier(2);
```

multiplier returns a function ,so twice is like this:

```js
twice = number => number * factor
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `multiplier` function returning an arrow function with value of `factor`, it is a different syntax for following simple definition.

```
function twice(number) {
   // Value 2 is part of function definition as returned from multiplier() function
   return number * 2;
}
```

In `console.log(twice(5))` you are passing parameter value 5, so it will return `5 * 2`.